# axis2 Log Response with Request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, axis

I am very new to Web Service.

I have one web service exposed, So client is consuming it but due to importance of service we want to Log SOAP Request and SOAP Response flowing IN and OUT.

I am using Axis2-1.6.2
This is what I tried so far, I wrote one custom Handler and Module class

```
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.engine.Handler;
import org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class LogHandler extends AbstractHandler implements Handler {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LogHandler.class);
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("LogHandler.getName()");
        return name;
    }

    public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
        log.info(msgContext.getEnvelope().toString());
        System.out.println("LogHandler.invoke()");
        return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;        
    }

    public void revoke(MessageContext msgContext) {
        System.out.println("LogHandler.revoke()");
        log.info(msgContext.getEnvelope().toString());
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("LogHandler.setName()");
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I also wrote Module for above Handler

```
public class LoggingModule implements Module {
   //implemented methods
}
```

From above Handler, I am able to Log Incoming SOAP Request and Outgoing SOAP Response.

But the Problem is, I am getting many request at a time, So If i write Plain Request and Response, then while looking at Logs I am not able to identify whose Response is this.

Logs in general it write

```
Request1 SOAP 
Request2 SOAP 
Response1 SOAP
Request3 SOAP
Request4 SOAP
Response2 SOAP
```

`invoke(MessageContext msgContext)` This method is getting invoked while request comes in and response goes out. Is there anything I can get request SOAP while response time it get called.

So, I want some solution where in I can consolidate Request SOAP in Response SOAP, So 1 Log is complete Request-Response both.

If any body can suggest some good solution for it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting request and response is logged, because you register your handler in both IN/OUT flows..

Say, if you register your handler at out flow, you will be able to pick your relevant request and response. That is, from response messgaecontext, you can access your request message context. from that, you can read your request message.[1]

But here you will see an issue, which if your request is failed, you wont be able to capture it in your outflow.That log might miss.

[1]http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/05/accessing-request-messagecontext-from.html

Comment: What is the way to register handler in IN Only or in OUT only? can you point some link. Also, If I register in IN-OUT, I will not get request in response?

Comment: can you explain your "But here you will see an issue, which if your request is failed, you wont be able to capture it in your outflow.That log might miss." lines.

Comment: If you register you handler at out flow, that will capture your response. But if your request is failed before that for some reason, you may not get response at out flow.SO that log entry might miss, but you can register the handler in the fault flows also ..

Comment: Got it. can you point me some link on how we implement similar logging in axis1.x ....as it has some different procedure... Thanks a lot Ratha.